# PDAL: how to create valid glb?

Tags: lidar, 3d, pdal

I'm attempting to create a glb model from a cropped laz file, using Python. The glb file is created successfully, but any reader (Blender, ThreeJS, online gltf validator) returns errors like:

`Bad glTF: json error: Extra data: line 1 column 4077 (char 4076)`

and

`ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 1`

My code (Python):

```
json = """
[
    "bc_093g087_3_3_4_xyes_8_utm10_2019.laz",
    {
        "type":"filters.crop",
        "point":"POINT(-122.76864141225815 53.89679683912206)",
        "distance": 50,
        "a_srs": "EPSG:4326"
    },
    {
        "type": "filters.poisson",
        "depth": 8
    },
    {
        "type":"writers.gltf",
        "filename":"output.glb"
    }
]
"""
pipeline = pdal.Pipeline(json)
pipeline.execute()
```

The output array (`pipeline.arrays[0]`) appears populated with x, y, z values (all other attributes are set to zero), and can be rendered successfully in a viewer like napari.

Data: https://nrs.objectstore.gov.bc.ca/gdwuts/093/093g/2019/pointcloud/bc_093g087_3_3_4_xyes_8_utm10_2019.laz

Are there any additional settings or processing I should be doing to create a valid gltf/glb model?

Some failed attempts:

- reproject points from 26910 to 4326
- filter only ground points to create a single continuous surface (full data includes floating features like powerlines)

Comment: Is the issue that when you read output.glb in a glTF viewer it doesn't work? Or you are trying to get the glb output as a Python object and are using that (not supported at the moment)?

Comment: It's the former. It seems the glb file is invalid when trying to read anywhere, but being binary, hard (impossible?) to debug.